# Guacamole RDP Control+C/Command+C doesn't work from MacOS

Tags: windows, macos, rdp, guacamole

I'm prototyping using `Apache Guacamole` for brokering RDP connections.
The tech stack works really well, however, I'm hitting a usability issue in regaurds to running a Mac and trying to send hot keys like Control+C/Command+C and them not working.

Per Guac's docs, this seems to be inline with what they expect, as they don't do any "curtesy" remapping that other RDP managers on Mac (Microsoft Remote Desktop, RDS HTML5 Client, etc) do.

My question is has anyone found a customization or workaround to allow `Mac->Win` keymapping through Guacemole HTMl5 interface?

I'm not sure its a none starter, but it is extremly difficult to use windows with nearly no keyboard shortcuts :).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On my mac I use BetterTouchTool to get around this issue. It's not great  though because your guacamole will still register the original keypresses from time to time. I have been looking for a workaround as well and have thus far not been able to find one :/.